# Connecting squid to upstream proxy using CONNECT request

Tags: proxy, squid, tunnel, connect

I'm setting up a reverse proxy that has to forward all the requests to a given url.com/resource. Now, that resource is behind a proxy, so it has to use the CONNECT request.
The idea is that squid, once it receives a request, creates an http tunnel using the CONNECT request, and then forwards that request to the desired server.

It does not have to be necessarily squid, it can be any other similar solution (nginx, apache, caddy).

Comment: The resource is behind a normal *forward* proxy?

Comment: No, behind a reverse proxy. I can access the resource using a curl request as: `curl -v url1.com/resource -k proxy.url.com --proxy-header 'Header1'`.

Comment: If it's behind a *reverse* proxy you don't need a connect or any special curl arguments. To me it looks like you're seeing a *forward* proxy, *not* a reverse one.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is behind a forward proxy. The one I want to make is a reverse one, my bad

Comment: I just re read my previous comment, the curl command is not ok, should be as follows:
`curl -k url1.com/resource -x proxy.url.com --proxy-header 'Header on'`